# How to get JSON into a Freemarker Template (FTL)

Tags: json, freemarker

I've got a MongoDB which I query and the result I serialize and this string I send to my ftl template. Below is the serialized result:

```
        [
            {
              "id" : "10",
              "title" : "Test Title 1",
              "partner" : {
                "id" : "1",
                "name" : "partner 1 ",   
                "location" : [{
                    "locationname" : "locationname 1a",
                    "city" : ""
                  },{
                    "locationname" : "locationname 1b",
                    "city" : ""
                    }]
              }
            },
            {
              "id" : "6",
              "title" : "Test Title 2",
              "partner" : {
                "id" : "1",
                "name" : "partner 2 ",   
                "location" : [{
                    "locationname" : "locationname 2b",
                    "city" : ""
                  }]
              }
            }  
        ]
```

How would I use this in my ftl template?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be more efficient if you don't serialize it... Do you really have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to serialize before giving the result to FreeMarker... The JSON syntax for maps and lists happens to be a subset of FTL, so assuming the serialized result is in `res`, `res?eval` will give you a list of maps.